# Отслеживание состояния элемента на странице

Tags: jquery

Как осуществить проверку на скрытие loader-a на странице?

Есть вот такой код:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#preloader-status').delay(700).fadeOut();
    $('#preloader').delay(1200).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Мне необходимо выполнить функцию, когда `$('#preloader')` будет скрыт.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для `fadeOut()` можно задать второй параметр, который является callback-ом.

Например:

```
$('#preloader').delay(1200).fadeOut('slow', yourFunction);
```

Функция `yourFunction` будет вызвана в конце отработки анимации, детальнее [тут](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D0%B8c%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8).

Answer (score 1):

у `fadeout` есть callback "animation complete".

```
$("#clickme").click(function() {
    $("#book").fadeOut("slow", function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

[jQuery fadeout](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/#fadeOut-duration-complete)